# Visual studio code - shortcut to open next file by name

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often find myself working on file `test-1a.robot` and I want to open `test-1b.robot`, which is the next alphabetical file in the editor list.

With the files are open and I have a "sort tabs" extension enabled I can use `ctrl+pgup` and `ctrl+pgdn` which is already something, but I'd like to have it even without the tab sorting or opening files in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to train yourself in the following key combo:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I tried to use [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) to create a combo of

1. show explorer tab
2. go to next file down
3. open this file

For (1.) I could find a command, it sets the focus on the current file in the Explorer.

**Edit** With the tip from mark for the commands to type the cursor down (2) and select command (3) in listboxes.

You can add this to your settings and create a key binding for this new command

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.openNextABCFile",
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.view.explorer",
        "list.focusDown",
        "list.select"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

It opens the next alphabetical filename in preview mode.

Comment: For item 2 & 3 it is probably just the `list.focusDown` and `list.select` commands. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: @Mark Thanks it works great, next time I take a closer look at the keybindings tab to see which command is bound to a particular key when XYZ has the focus